# random start in drools

Tags: java, drools

Currently my drl file looks like something like this with 100+ rules.

```
rule "check 0"
when
   .....
then
..........
end


rule "check 1"
when
   .....
then
..........
end

rule "check 2"
when
   .....
then
..........
end

.
.
.
.

rule "check 100"
when
   .....
then
..........
end
```

and I have set `sessionObject.fireAllRules(1);`

So this basically iterate through all the rules from `rule 'check 0'` to `rule 'check 100'` and returns when ever it falls under some rule.

Is their a way where I can start at some random rule instead of starting `rule 'check 0'` every time.

I am looking for something like this.

Start from say `rule 'check 34'` iterate till `rule 'check 100'` and iterate from rule `'check 0'` to `rule 'check 33'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of testing a condition and executing an action if it is true is as old as computers. Likewise, the concept of ordering actions is just as old. Both have been implemented in various versions of what is now known as "procedural programming".

The requirements you describe meet, and are met by, "procedural programming" head-on.

Of course, Drools can be made to behave very much like a procedural program. So, to answer your question: Yes it's possible, by using salience.

```
rule "to  be fired first"
salience 999999999
when ... then ... end
```

Simply use decreasing values, and this defines the order.

**Edit** 
The idea of randomizing rule firing isn't in the rule-based-programming paradigm either. But you can mimick this (why don't you use procedural programming??) by deriving salience from a fact attribute.

Create 100 objects of a class Ranking with fields `int order` and `int rank`. Insert them with `order` set to 1..100 and `rank` to a random permutation of 1..100.

```
rule "number 49"
salience $rank
when
    Ranking( order == 49, $rank: rank )
    ...
then ... end
```

For the next run, simply use another permutation. The rule lucky to catch a Ranking with `rank==100` will fire first.

Comment: Yeah!I know this :) But the question is how to randomise it.On first run lets say it starts at rule 34.In second run it can start at any other rule like rule 45.Is this possible.

Comment: @starkk92 Edited to include a way for randomizing rule priority.